# Making elements of an array divisible by three

Tags: number-theory, invariance

> Consider the following $6$x$6$ array 
>   $$
> \begin{matrix}
> 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{matrix}
> $$
>   One can choose a $k$x$k$ subarray where $1\lt k\lt 6$ and then add $1$ to all elements. Is it possible to perform this action a finite number of times such that every element in the array is a multiple of three?

The sum of all elements in the array is $26$. For all the elements to be divisible by $3$, even the sum has to be divisible by $3$. Choosing a $2$x$2$ subarray will add a total of $4$ to the total sum. A $3$x$3$ will add $9$, a $4$x$4$ will add $16$ and a $5$x$5$ will add $25$. All except a $3$x$3$ subarray will result in the sum being divisible by three. So we can't show it's impossible like this.

I guess some invariant has to be found here, considering the symmetry of the top left $4$x$4$ subarray.  Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't quite get what you are trying to do. If you start with two numbers, $n$ and $n+1$ and will increase each number by one until one of them is a multiple of three, the other number won't be divisible by three

Comment: @Vasya, that's correct, but we're not choosing every number in the array here, just a smaller square subarray such that it only increases some numbers, leaving the others unchanged. The question asks whether such a combination of actions can be achieved such that every number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: if you can increase elements by different values, why not just add matrix to itself three times:$a+a+a$ will be divisible by three

Comment: We need to find a combination of selecting some subarray and increasing the values such that the increase is equivalent to the array itself. What you said is a possible solution, but you can't just add the array to itself.

Comment: we can cover 6x6 matrix with non-intersecting 2x2 arrays and apply consecutive additions to each 2x2 array

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more as an answer? I'm having some trouble visualising it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide the original matrix 
$$
\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

into four $3$x$3$ matrices:
$$
\begin{array}{lcr|lcr}
2 & 0 & 1 &0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\hline \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Then each $3$x$3$ matrix $A_i$ we transform into matrix $B_i=A_i+A_i+A_i$ to get the final result:
$$
\begin{matrix}
6 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: I guess I understood what you were trying to tell, we can't apply normal transformations to this matrix, we can only choose a smaller square matrix and increase the elements by $1$. Unless you can apply this action to get your transformation, this doesn't answer the question